# How to make user profile picture bigger | discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

The issue I am having is that every time I make the bot display someones avatar its significantly smaller to what other bots display like Dyno and sx4. Example:

[image]

**How would I make the image bigger?(my bot is the one named "Azrael")**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try: `user.displayAvatarURL({size: 2048})`

displayAvatarURL() method is better than avatarURL() because it also shows user's avatar if they have discord default one.

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=displayAvatarURL

Answer (score 1):

The [`MessageEmbedImage` object](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageEmbedImage) has a `height` and `width` property you can set. For more information on embed image objects, visit [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#embed-object-embed-image-structure)